# Regex: I want to separate addresses that include some exceptions

Tags: regex

Rules I'm trying to apply:

Group 1 must always contain text, and if the string starts with "the" then also include it.

Group 2 is optional and can be (street or road).

Group 3 is optional and can contain (east or west).

I've got most of the way with the following (I think):

```
(.+?)\b\s?((?i)ROAD|STREET)*.?((?<= +)(?i)WEST|EAST)?$
```

but with a couple of exceptions:
"the street" is separated but needs to all be in Group 1 as it starts with a "the".
"STREET" is in Group 2 but needs to be in Group 1 as Group 1 always needs a value

| Text | Match | Position | Length | Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| smith | smith | 0 | 5 | smith |  |  |
| the street | the street | 5 | 11 | the | street |  |
| STREET | STREET | 16 | 7 |  | STREET |  |
| the street west | the street west | 23 | 16 | the | street | west |
| smith street | smith street | 39 | 13 | smith | street |  |
| smith road | smith road | 52 | 11 | smith | road |  |
| smith strreet east | smith strreet east | 63 | 19 | smith strreet |  | east |
| SMITH | SMITH | 82 | 6 | SMITH |  |  |
| SMITH Street | SMITH Street | 88 | 13 | SMITH | Street |  |
| SMITH Street | SMITH Street | 101 | 14 | SMITH | Street |  |
| Smith Street West abc | Smith Street West abc | 115 | 22 | Smith Street West abc |  |  |
| Smith Street East | Smith Street East | 137 | 18 | Smith | Street | East |
| Smith SttReet East | Smith SttReet East | 155 | 19 | Smith SttReet |  | East |
| Smith Street West | Smith Street West | 174 | 18 | Smith | Street | West |

Comment: _Because regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool._

Answer (score 0):

```
((.+?)\b\s?((?i)ROAD|STREET)*).?((?<=)(?i)WEST|EAST)?$
```

I did two changes:

1. I removed white space and plus symbol  `+`. It fixes the blank group 1
2. I have grouped the `the` and `street`. Both appears in group 1 if they exist

Comment: That now makes 4 groups and "the street" is in group 1 but components of this: "the" is in Group 2 and "street" is in Group 3.